# Python String replace behaves differently

Tags: python, string

The below string replace code prints "XXaXXbXXcXX1XX2XX3XX". I know there is a reason behind it but having hard time finding it. Can someone please explain why?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    match = ""
    replace = "XX"
    strr = "abc123"
    print strr.replace(match, replace)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's replacing the empty string between each pair of characters with XX.

Comment: And the empty strings at the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You replace every "" (empty string) by "XX". Python consider that between two character there is a empty string!!! And before the first character and after the last.
It's just that!

Comment: 'It's just that'. Exactly the confirmation I wanted to hear. Thanks!